# Windows Explorer in Windows 7 not responding

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

In Windows 7, whenever I try to open any folder on my D: drive in Windows Explorer, it shows a dialog box indicating:

> Windows Explorer is not responding.

Windows Explorer then closes automatically.  I am unable to open my important files on the D: drive.

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you run a check desk on the D: drive?  Right click the d: drive, Properties, Tools, Error Checking - Check Now.